# Join 3 tables in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables

`_virtuemart_product_medias` contains

```
'Full texts'    'id'    'virtuemart_product_id'     'virtuemart_media_id'   'ordering'
```

`_virtuemart_products_pl_pl` contains

```
 'virtuemart_product_id'    'product_s_desc'    'product_desc'  'product_name'
 'metadesc'     'metakey'   'customtitle'   'slug'
```

`_virtuemart_medias` contains

```
'virtuemart_media_id'   'virtuemart_vendor_id'  'file_title'
'file_description'  'file_meta'     'file_mimetype'     'file_type'
'file_url'
```

How to get `_virtuemart_products_pl_pl (*), _virtuemart_products_pl_pl (*)`

where

```
_virtuemart_products_pl_pl.virtuemart_product_id = _virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_product_id
AND
_virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_media_id = _virtuemart_medias.virtuemart_media_id
```

I need sql query, but I don't know how to build it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1, t2, t3
where t1.id=t2.id
and t2.id=t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vpp.* 
    FROM _virtuemart_product_medias vpm
        JOIN _virtuemart_products_pl_pl vpp ON vpm.virtuemart_product_id = vpp.virtuemart_product_id
        JOIN _virtuemart_medias vm ON vpm.virtuemart_media_id = vm.virtuemart_media_id
```

You stated that you want two _virtuemart_products_pl_pl tables in the result. If you need other table, just add ,vm.* or ,vpm.* after vpp.* (remember to separate each distinct table with comma).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use innerjoin function of PHP/SQL that joins different tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select table1.name,table3.name from table1,table2,table3 
where table1.uid = table2.person_id and table3.user_id = table1.uid
```

you will get form this friend.Accept answer if it useful for you